# In Emgucv How to measure pixel width and height?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I want to learn image processing. I made a program. I compared two images using emgucv. But ı want to meausere pixel width and height. How can ı do it ?

I read but there is no example with emgucv.  I have no professional camera. I will use web cam for the present. And ı will use coin to measure pixel width and height. But the problem is ı don't know how will do it.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a factor mm/pixel you have to capture an image of an object of known size. The object must reside within the plane where you want to do your measurements. for a normal setup this is a plane parallel to the camera sensor.

Then count the number of pixels along a known dimension of your object. Divide that metric dimension by the number of pixels.

Once you have that factor you can use that to measure any dimension withn that plane by counting the number of pixels and multiply that with that factor.

This approach is sufficient for most layman's tasks.